# In a WebFlux application, form data is accessed via ServerWebExchange.getFormData()

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I'm trying to access the request body of a request in a Spring Webflux application but when I try to do so I get the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: In a WebFlux application, form data is accessed via ServerWebExchange.getFormData().
```

Using this code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/in")
public ResponseEntity<?> receiveSms(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> params) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

If i use the ServerWebExchange.getFormData() I get an empty list of params.

Comment: Do you have Content-Type header set as application/x-www-form-urlencoded ?

Comment: Yes I have @SKumar

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can do something like:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/in")
public ResponseEntity<?> receiveSms(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
    return serverWebExchange.getFormData()
               .flatMap(multiValueMap -> {

                   // process multiValueMap here

               }).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().build())
}
```